# How to open native file explorer to locate a directory in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to call the native file explorer and get the selected directory path ?

Comment: The [file_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/file_picker) package might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing, and could not find a UI type plugin so I built a page which more or less is a File Explorer.
I utilized the [flutter_file_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_manager) plugin to get a list of files in the desired directory, and then returned the (future) list into a series of ListTile's via ListView.builder.

```
List<FileSystemEntity> _fileList;

Future<void> _loadFiles() async {
  _loadingFiles = true;

  var root = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  _fileList = await FileManager(root: root).walk().toList();

  _loadingFiles = false;

  this.setState(() {});
}
```

Once you have the _fileList object, you can pretty much do whatever you want.
For example, I added a PopupMenuButton in my AppBar and under there I allow file delete, open, etc.

With each item in the _fileList List, you can also display the filename, size, modified date, etc in your ListTile's.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find an official way to do it, so I did it in another way. I used the library "[path_provider](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/path_provider)"， Through the "Directory" method, for example, through the method “directory.list” Get the files in the directory. In this way, you can traverse all the directories and files. Then write a page to display the directory, so as to achieve the effect of native file explore.Also, don't forget about permissions

```
_getSDCardDirectory() async {
  Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  print(directory.path);
  await directory.list().toList().then((filesList) => print(filesList));
  print(directory.parent.path);
}
```

Comment: it did not give download directory path

Answer (score 1):

Write a method in kotlin / java and call it from flutter via MethodChannels.
Start native file manager as below..

```
startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
```

Refer this link below to know alot about [MethodChannels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Answer (score 1):

You can try plugin [filesystem_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/filesystem_picker), which supports mobile and desktop platforms and also support nullsafety in its newest 2.0+ version

```
import 'package:filesystem_picker/filesystem_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Directory rootPath = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String? path = await FilesystemPicker.open(title: 'Save to folder',
      context: context,
      rootDirectory: rootPath,
      fsType: FilesystemType.folder,
      pickText: 'Save file to this folder',
      folderIconColor: Colors.teal,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code below. No packages required

```
import 'dart:io';

  void openDirectory(String path) {
Process.run(
  "explorer",
  [path],
  workingDirectory: path,
  );
}
```

This code execute a shell command(opening the file explorer on windows). This will enable you to open your desired folder